# EF 5/6 in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

quick question really. Is the Entity Framework 5/6 supported in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I was told it is not supported and wanted to know if someone has tried it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

correct if you are targeting core. You could target the **full framework** though (even in your asp.net core application)

csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6

Comment: if this is done, would the code execute on a linux machine?

Comment: "if this is done, would the code execute on a linux machine?" - obviously no

Comment: @TimurLemeshko - No it Will not as the .Net framework runs on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, Entity Framework 6 is not supported by .net core 2.0

But you have some options:

1. Reference *net461* in your project (as it described by user1859022). Then you will able to use full framework libraries, but only on Windows machines.
2. Reference "*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*" nuGet package and use Entity Framework Core. It will let you to use it on Linux. But Entity Framework Core is not so good as Entity Framework 6 yet and unfortunately have some restrictions.

Comment: "Entity Framework Core is not so good as Entity Framework 6" I think that's a matter of opinion, no?

Comment: I was trying to use it in my production projects. First of all, you just can't migrate from EF6 to EF Core, you will have to rewrite your model and all data-access layer (all of them). Second, even if you are starting a new project, there is some serious restrictions. For example, there is no way to use many-to-many relations without explicit middle entity (EF6 can). If your model is not for "Hello world!"  application, it will bring you to hell. I beleave MS will fix it in next versions

Comment: There's also support for other database vendors, like Postgresql, which is not possible with EF6. So, it depends on what you're using it for and how, so it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: As far as you are using trivial queries only it is indeed a matter of opinion / use-case. Beyond other serious limitations the biggest downside of the core version (even in 2.0) is that it cannot do server-side GROUP BY. This is deal breaker for me. This is to change with EF Core 2.1 (currently in preview).